# Search function on site not working

Tags: html

The search function on my site doesn't work - it just keeps saying 'searching' and doesn't display results like it used to.

I've tried looking at the coding changes I had made to my site that may have caused this issue but am unable to solve it.

Here's my [site](http://xojaynee.com). Does anyone have any clue as to why my search function has stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your log gives the following error:

> ReferenceError: Mustache is not defined

My Guess is that MustacheJs is not being loaded properly, Can't really help much more without having access to the entire code, Hope that helps you...

Answer (score 0):

If you see in Chrome debugger tools -> Console window, as soon as you start typing in search box, it gives this error:

scripts.v-287efa1….js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Mustache is not defined

and it points to this file: http://db94kr1tell4s.cloudfront.net/static/js/storefront/scripts.v-287efa18903967e695f9b7579da48a25.js

So, it seems like you are missing some library for sure.

Comment: yodamaul responded at the same time I was posting, no offense.